# Two port network analysis

Tags: circuit-analysis, network, cascade, 2-port-network

[image]
In the given problem we were required to calculate the input impedance of the given two port cascaded network.
So my approach was that I first calculated the transmission parameters as given below

[image]

And then I assumed V2 = 0, and then I multiplied V1/I2 with I2/I1 which turned out to be B/D, but the answer given is A/C (considering I2=0). So is my solution wrong if yes then why?

Comment: Why did you assume V2 = 0? That would mean no signal has been transmitted to the load. For that matter, why assume I2 = 0? Was the text solving for the particular case where ZL is an open circuit?

Comment: The transmission parameters are ABCD parameters so V1=A(V2)+B(-I2) and I1=C(V2)+D(-I2). That's why when I assumed V2 =0 I was getting the following results.

Answer (score 0):

Once the ABCD parameters of the quadripole were known, I determined the equivalent circuit with Z parameters and applied the load Zload. By applying a test generator to the input, I calculated the input impedance.

[image]